# JSON Object tree recursion with underscore and backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

Say I have a json object with nested arrays to unknown depths. I want to feed each array into a _.template function. For Example, my json object might look like:

```
$start_elements = array (
        array(
            "elementTag"=>"li",
            "elementClass"=>"dashboard",
            "elementContent"=>array(
                "elementTag"=>"a",
                "elementContent"=>"Dashboard",
                "href"=>"#home"
                ) 
        ),
        array(
            "elementTag"=>"li", 
            "elementClass"=>"count indicator", 
            "elementContent"=>array(
                array(
                    "elementTag"=>"span", 
                    "elementClass"=>"data-count='8'", 
                    "elementContent"=>"Notifications"
                ), 
                array(
                    "elementTag"=>"ul", 
                    "elementClass"=>" ",
                    "elementContent"=>array(
                        "elementTag"=>"li", 
                        "elementContent"=>array(
                            "elementTag"=>"a",
                            "href"=>"#", 
                            "elementExtra"=>"data-modal",
                            "elementContent"=>array(
                                array(
                                    "elementTag"=>"h4",
                                    "elementContent"=>"Lorem Ipsum"
                                    ), 
                                array(
                                    "elementTag"=>"<p>",
                                    "elementContent"=>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit imet smd ddm lksdm lkdsm"
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
);
json_encode($start_elements);
```

_.template:

```
_.template('<<%= elementTag %> class="<%= elementClass %>" href="<%= href %>"><%= elementContent %></<%= elementTag %>')
```

The nested structure of the arrays is significant because I want to output the html in the same nested structure. For example, the above object would output an li object with an anchor tag inside of it. How do I go about applying the template to each nested array, while preserving this structure?

Comment: That's no JSON, and I don't see any arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make a wrapper function around your template to keep your template logicless. Then you can use underscore's utility methods to check if you have an array, object (or string) (`_.isArray` and `_.isObject`) in your hands.

You'll need to pass in your wrapper function into the template so you can use it. You can just `_.extend` your data with `{tmpl: tmpl}`.

Here's a working, though simplified, example:

```
    var data = {
    elementTag: "li",
    elementContent: [{
        elementTag: "a",
        elementContent: "Dashboard"
    }, {
        elementTag: "div",
        elementContent: "Hello"
    }]
};

var tmpl = _.template('<<%= elementTag %>><%= template(elementContent) %></<%= elementTag %>>');

function template(elData) {
    var html = "";
    if (_.isArray(elData)) {
        _.each(elData, function (el) {
            html += template(el);
        });
    } else if (_.isObject(elData)) {
        html = tmpl(_.extend({
            template: template
        }, elData));
    } else {
        html = elData;
    }
    return html;
}

console.log(template(data));
```

Comment: What happens if the child elements in elementContent are arrays and not objects? (See edited answer above). Should some sort of _.each iteration happen in the case of arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
function applyTemplate(obj){
  if _.has(obj, "elementContent"){
     obj.elementContent = applyTemplate(obj.elementContent)
  }
  return _.template("templateString", obj)
}
```

Basically you go through the whole tree and replace the `elementContent` with its template value going bottom to up.

Comment: Will this loop? I can't seem to get it working but I think it may be just trying to return the deepest object in template...

Comment: I should work, I didn't test it but it would go through the all tree and then replace all `elementContent` and replace them in the object. Please also note that your example doesn't represent a tree but a stack.

Comment: What happens if the child elements in elementContent are arrays and not objects? (See edited answer above). Should some sort of _.each iteration happen in the case of arrays?

Comment: Then you replace `obj.elementContent = applyTemplate(obj.elementContent)` by `obj.elementContent = obj.elementContent.map(function(obj1){ return applyTemplate(obj1.elementContent)})`